# VLC wont install from Software Center in 16.04 - can't install from terminal

Tags: software-center, vlc, 16.04

I recently dual booted a laptop with the recently released 16.04. I first attempted to install VLC media player from the Software Center, and like many others I'm unable to do that (or any third party applications).

I then attempted to install VLC from the terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

I receive an error stating I have unmet dependencies:

```
"Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vlc : Depends: vlc-nox (= 1:2.0.6-dmo3) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libavcodec54 (>= 8:1.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify (= 1:2.0.6-dmo3) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-pulse (= 1:2.0.6-dmo3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages."
```

I've tried every fix listed for similar problems I could find on this site but none seem to correct my issue.

Comment: Please review URL http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa for you answer.

Comment: Apologies but I had seen this particular response and had done everything in it. I still show unmet dependencies and am unable to install VLC

Comment: The "unmet dependencies" you show in your question differ from the depends list of [vlc in Xenial](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/vlc). From where did you get vlc?

Comment: If you are using Deb Multimedia with Ubuntu then shame on you, issues will occur.